# Convert JGW to Slippy Map Tiles

Tags: world-file, slippy

I've been given a JPG and JGW that needs to be converted into tiles viewable on a mapbox map as slippy tiles.

I've been told the image co-ordinates are in https://epsg.io/3116

I've confirmed the jgw files is as the spec: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

I've tried using [qgis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) with [QMetaTiles](https://bitbucket.org/we-do-it/qgis-latlongo-stage-1/wiki/Home) by:

1. creating a new project
2. setting the projects CRG to EPSG:3116
3. Creating a new Rater Layer and importing the image
4. Checked the raster layers properties and confirmed they are using the co-ordinates from the jgw file
5. Using QMetatiles to export the layer using Layer Extent option.

When doing this I just get a bunch of blank tiles.

I then tried the free version of [maptiler](https://www.maptiler.com/)

1. Load the image
2. Geolocation seemed to pickup the jgw file, but the co-ordinates were not exact.
3. Set the coordinates field to EPSG:3116
4. Export the tileset.

This seems to work better, at least I was getting the map visible on the tiles, but it's not appearing on the map where it should be.

How can I reliably export this file as a tileset?
Other than the EPSG:3116 coordinate system, should I be asking for more information?
Are there any other (free) solutions for doing this?

Comment: Mapbox is in 3857, so you will need to make sure the projection is correct. I think gdal2tiles will actually reproject it for you if I remember correctly. It's an easy and free way to tile GeoTIFFs

Comment: This is the one occasion when it is correct to use the set crs option on your layer, rather than relying on the projection of the project

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more searching I was able to find [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSX3Y0SchUg).
The QMetaTile plugin is no longer required

Also rather than drawing the extent, setting the layer's Properties > Source > CRS to EPSG:3116. Then in the Generate XYZ Tiles tool, select "calculate from layer" in the Extent field pop-up.